# Can you clarify the distinction between __builtins__ and builtins in python

Tags: python, python-module, built-in

There are many builtin functions that you can use without having to import anything. These include things like `pow()`, `open()`, `sum()`, `max()`, etc.  However, if you want to see the complete list with `dir()`, you must first import builtins.

If you do a `dir(builtins)` without first importing `builtins`, you get

```
>>> dir(builtins)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'builtins' is not defined
```

How is it possible to use these functions without importing builtins, yet builtins must be imported to see the complete list?

Moreover, there is something else called  `"__builtins__"`  which you can use with `dir()` without importing it. But this produces an entirely different list of functions.

This is very confusing. Why are there two builtins and why do they behave differently?

By the way, I’m running `Python 3.7.11` on a Mac. Maybe things are different in another version.

Comment: it's possible to define local names which hide the builtin names. If you want to restore the originals they still exist in the `builtins` modules

Comment: *this produces an entirely different list of functions.* - are you sure?

Comment: `__builtins__` is a built-in module that provides a minimal set of built-in names automatically available in Python, while `builtins` is an actual module that extends the functionality with additional built-in names that need to be imported explicitly.

Comment: @peter wood,  you bring up yet another complication. The reason I said you get a different list of functions is that I ran dir("__builtins__").  But dir(__builtins__), without the quotes, which I did not run until now, produces the same list as dir(builtins).  Also, you don't have to import anything to see the function names with dir(__builtins__). You only have to import builtins if you want to see the function names with  dir(builtins).

Comment: `dir("builtins")` will give all the attributes on a string object. You might as well have typed `dir("rkg125")` and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says pretty much everything there is to say:

> ## `builtins` — Built-in objects
>
> This module provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python [..]
>
> This module is not normally accessed explicitly by most applications, but can be useful in modules that provide objects with the same name as a built-in value, but in which the built-in of that name is also needed.
>
> [..]
>
> As an implementation detail, most modules have the name `__builtins__` made available as part of their globals. The value of `__builtins__` is normally either this module or the value of this module’s `__dict__` attribute. Since this is an implementation detail, it may not be used by alternate implementations of Python.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html

In other words, *the module* `builtins` holds a bunch of "built-in" functions, which are so regularly needed that the language makes them available to your programs implicitly without you needing to explicitly `import` them. This is merely as a convenience for the programmer. You *can* explicitly `import builtins` if you need to, but usually you don't (because the contents of `builtins` is already available in every module).

`__builtins__` exists as a side-effect of this magically-available-in-every-module logic. It's an implementation detail you should not pay much attention to.

`"__builtins__"` is merely an arbitrary string with no further meaning. `dir("__builtins__")` is the same as `dir("foo")` or `dir("")`; it examines a string object.